# The best way to provide access to Ninject kernel to get concrete implementations of interfaces

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, windows-phone, ninject

We're using Ninject for DI in our WP app and due to architectural decisions almost all objects created via Ninject were created as singletons. However we're moving towards using Ninject to provide concrete instances and we're not sure what sort of solution would be the best choice regarding access to Ninject kernel. How would you wrap the kernel to provide conrete implementations of interfaces? One universal class? That seems a bit broad. Factories for every single interface? Seems very granular. Service providers with wider scope (say, per project)?

Comment: If you do proper DI, then you *inject* dependencies into classes, the classes don't ask for them! So why would the classes need access to the kernel? Of course there's *some* cases where you need to do that.. in that cases a factory / abstract factory is a good idea.
I'd suggest you read Mark Seeman's book on dependency injection. And maybe get started with his articles [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/) and [Service Locator is an Anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). The comments contain interesting information, too!

Comment: Can you provide a code example, where you really need access to kernel? I am pretty sure you can avoid it in 99% places.